# UITableView Gap Xcode 5

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

I'm having trouble adding a UITableView to a UIViewController in Xcode 5 (DP4). When I add the table view and add a cell to the table through Interface Builder Storyboards, the table adds an extra white gap/space above the first cell. This seems to be happening when I embed the view controller in a Navigation Controller.

When I build and run the space is still there so it's not just a quirk in IB.

See the picture below to see what I mean.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgqolwmo02h91d6/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-20%20at%2011.52.27.png

This doesn't happen on Xcode 4.6

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8giyj2mjdhcrhy4/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-20%20at%2012.37.06.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the Table View can't be the first child of the view controller's view. Drag it down below another view to fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: Sorry to ask you straight up, when I could actually test this myself but..... Is this only the case now in XCode 5 because of iOS 7 and the translucent Navigation Bar - so the very first child is expected to stretch under the Bar to be visible. I guess that kind makes sense alright!

Comment: Not sure, that would make sense tho.

Comment: If you need to have the TableView at the top of the view, you can add a 1pt view with a negative -1pt top constraint above the TableView to fix this, like so: [Autolayout Fix](http://i.imgur.com/9AYAjaR.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want more help, you'll need to go on Apple's developer forum (NDA, blah blah blah), but I'd say have a look at your constraints. Keep a backup of your XCode 4 story and upgrade it in XCode 5, you might see what is wrong.

Comment: I never thought about any NDA things.... I got it to work but something weird is still going on.... can I even say how I did it? You have me running scared DCMaxxx!

Comment: Don't worry, Apple won't ban your account because you asked a question or what. But since iOS 7 is still under private betas, you should normally not discuss it outside of the dev center ;-)

Comment: Please @RobertKeogh can you tell us how did you fix it?

Comment: 1. I removed the table in question. 2. I dropped a small UIView into the ViewController. 3. I made that view transparent. 4. Then re-added the table.....It looks like the UITableView doesnt like to be in there first! The exact same happened with a UIScrollView I was working with. This is a complete hack of course.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a UITableView to a blank view canvas it adds a 20 pt constraint to the top to account for the status bar. Embedding the UITableView in a navigation controller after this constraint was already set added this padding to the top of the UITableView. I found this constraint in XCode but no matter what I did I couldn't remove it. What I ended up doing was removing the UITableView from the View and then adding it back and the constraint was gone. The UITableView remained the first child of the view so I don't think that's a specific requirement.